Problem with calling swapExactTokensForETH
Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to implement a function that calls swapExactTokensForETH on Pancake Swap.
I have successfully implemented something that calls swapExactETHForTokens which executes fine, however going in the opposite direction always results in a failed transaction on BscScan.
If I use the Testnet router the transaction executes without a problem.
Is there anything I could be missing that would cause failure on Main but executes on Test?

Show us your code and transaction hash
